# Getting the text that follows after the regex match

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to using Regex, I've been going through a rake of tutorials but I haven't found one that applies to what I want to do,

I want to search for something, but return everything following it but not the search string itself

e.g. "*Some lame sentence that is awesome*"

search for "*sentence*"

return "*that is awesome*"

Any help would be much appreciated

This is my regex so far

```
sentence(.*)
```

but it returns: **sentence that is awesome**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("sentence(.*)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("some lame sentence that is awesome");

boolean found = false;
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println("I found the text: " + matcher.group().toString());
    found = true;
}
if (!found)
{
    System.out.println("I didn't find the text");
}
```

Comment: What is your actual call? Are you using `Matcher`?

Comment: I'm using matcher and pattern

Comment: ... and we'd still like to see your actual Java code in order to help evaluate what's wrong.

Comment: `System.out.println("I found the text: " + "some lame sentance that is aweomse".substring(end()));`

Comment: +1 if you're a grammar nazi like me

Comment: @DavidIsNotHere Nazi should have a capital N...

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You can do this with "just the regular expression" as you asked for in a comment:

```
(?<=sentence).*
```

`(?<=sentence)` is a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This matches at a certain position in the string, namely at a position right after the text `sentence` without making that text itself part of the match. Consequently, `(?<=sentence).*` will match any text after `sentence`.

This is quite a nice feature of regex. However, in Java this will only work for finite-length subexpressions, i. e. `(?<=sentence|word|(foo){1,4})` is legal, but `(?<=sentence\s*)` isn't.

Comment: You state that it should not include the positive lookbehind assertion. So I assume that ".*(?<=sentence)" should return everything up to, but not including "sentence". But it doesn't, it returns "sentence" as well. What am I missing?

Comment: @user2184214: That's because it's a look*behind* assertion. `.*` matches any text, and then `(?<=...)` looks backwards for the word `sentence`, asserting in this case that the match ends with that word. If you want to stop before that word, you need to look *ahead*: `.*(?=sentence)` will match any text that is followed by `sentence`.

Comment: For anyone looking for a way to match any text after one or another string, regexps like `(?<=sentence1|sentence2).*`, ``(?:(?<=sentence1)|(?<=sentence2)).*`` or even `(?:sentence1|sentence2)(.*)` might work.

Comment: Great thanks! I was using your answer to find everything after a plus sign. So just for another example: `(?<=\+).*`

Answer (score 22):

Your regex `"sentence(.*)"` is right. To retrieve the contents of the group in parenthesis, you would call:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "sentence(.*)" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( "some lame sentence that is awesome" );
if ( m.find() ) {
   String s = m.group(1); // " that is awesome"
}
```

Note the use of `m.find()` in this case (attempts to find anywhere on the string) and not `m.matches()` (would fail because of the prefix "some lame"; in this case the regex would need to be `".*sentence(.*)"`)

Comment: Thanks, But what if I just want it to return "that is awesome"

Comment: Thanks man, this worked great, I was hoping there was a way to do this with just the regular expression, if I cant find a way to do it that way, this will work aswell

Comment: Likely a bad idea to add a "(.*)" at the end of the regexp for the performance...

Answer (score 10):

if Matcher is initialized with `str`, after the match, you can get the part after the match with

```
str.substring(matcher.end())
```

**Sample Code:**

```
final String str = "Some lame sentence that is awesome";
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("sentence").matcher(str);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(str.substring(matcher.end()).trim());
}
```

**Output:**

> that is awesome

Comment: `matcher.find()` is required before this, IMO.

Comment: @Nishant that's what I wrote: "after the match". Added sample code to illustrate

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the *group(int)* of your matcher - group(0) is the entire match, and group(1) is the first group you marked. In the example you specify, group(1) is what comes after "**sentence**".

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put "group(1)" instead of "group()" in the following line and the return will be the one you expected:

```
System.out.println("I found the text: " + matcher.group(**1**).toString());
```