# Regex to get the words after matching string

Tags: regex, expression, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Below is the content:

```
Subject:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-21-3368353891-1012177287-890106238-22451
    Account Name:       ChamaraKer
    Account Domain:     JIC
    Logon ID:       0x1fffb

Object:
    Object Server:  Security
    Object Type:    File
    Object Name:    D:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\logs\localhost.2013-07-01.log
    Handle ID:  0x11dc
```

I need to capture the words after the `Object Name:` word in that line. Which is `D:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\logs\localhost.2013-07-01.log`.

How can I do this?

`^.*\bObject Name\b.*$` matches - Object Name

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you are using a regex engine that doesn't support `\K`, the following should work for you:

```
[\n\r].*Object Name:\s*([^\n\r]*)
```

[Working example](http://rubular.com/r/hpweFWWB87)

Your desired match will be in capture group 1.

---

```
[\n\r][ \t]*Object Name:[ \t]*([^\n\r]*)
```

Would be similar but not allow for things such as " blah Object Name: blah" and also make sure that not to capture the next line if there is no actual content after "Object Name:"

Comment: But i need the match result to be `D:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\logs\localhost.2013-07-01.log` not in a match group

Comment: @CasperNine, why? And what language are you using?

Comment: because the program im using captures only match result. Im using a log management tool called logstash. put your regex to this site http://regexpal.com/ and see.. it matches the whole line.

Comment: @CasperNine, it depends on if that supports lookbehinds. Try this and let me know your result: `(?<=Object Name:)([^\n\r]*)` See [here](http://rubular.com/r/jKUqWN2Tb1)

Comment: @CasperNine, then you'll have to either use capture groups or base it off the following line like this: `[^\s]+(?=\s+Handle ID:)` The problem with this is that it isn't flexible so if your format or order changes at all it wont work.

Comment: n̶o̶p̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶ ̶:̶(̶ . Sorry it Works. but keeps a blank space at the beginning of the match line/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38647/discussion-between-caspernine-and-smerny)

Comment: In lookbehinds you cannot use quantifiers so you could remove the blank space by putting the exact amount of spaces... but this wouldn't be flexible if you have varying number of spaces between the key/value pair.

Comment: I have one more question from you. How do i use `[^\s]+(?=\s+Handle ID:)` when the string is something like `Object Name: F:\Shared\Full_Option\Standed sinhala letters\Lalith\~$rapt order.doc`? Something with spaces

Comment: @CasperNine, you could try matching against newlines instead of any space characters... `[^\r\n]+(?=\s+Handle ID:)`

Comment: For any future visitors, I strongly suggest looking at @hwnd answer which captures the need better and is a more general purpose solution

Comment: depends on the regex engine being used.

Answer (score 75):

> But I need the match result to be ... not in a match group...

For what you are trying to do, this should work. `\K` resets the starting point of the match.

```
\bObject Name:\s+\K\S+
```

You can do the same for getting your `Security ID` matches.

```
\bSecurity ID:\s+\K\S+
```

Comment: `\K` not working in javascript, any other solutions?

Comment: This worked great for me in Notepad++. I'm not sure what regex processor it uses, but it does allow the \K when doing regex searches.

Comment: regexr says \K works only with PCRE and not in javascript, no clue what PCRE is though, seems server sided stuff.

Answer (score 20):

You're almost there. Use the following regex (with multi-line option enabled)

```
\bObject Name:\s+(.*)$
```

The complete match would be

```
Object Name:   D:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\logs\localhost.2013-07-01.log
```

while the captured group one would contain

```
D:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\logs\localhost.2013-07-01.log
```

---

If you want to capture the file path directly use

```
(?m)(?<=\bObject Name:).*$
```

Comment: I want the complete match to be `D:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\logs\localhost.2013-07-01.log` can't i do that?

Comment: @CasperNine Yes, you can. Updated the regex.

Comment: @hwnd yes thats correct. But how that actually works? what if need to match words which are in the line `Security ID:`

Comment: @CasperNine, did you try `(?m)(?<=\bObject Name:).*$`?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal your updated regex keeps a blank space in front of the line. how do i avoid that?

Comment: @CasperNine, I guess it's not possible for you to trim it but variable length look-behind is not supported with almost all the regex engines. You could use `(?m)(?<=\bObject Name:\s{4}).*$` but it would fail for others like `Security ID:` because the amount of whitespace varies.

Comment: @hwnd: that would fail if the file structure changes (re-ordered or the next token is dropped).

Comment: Yes, I saw that, I posted an answer on how he could do it.

Comment: @RaviKThapliyal I need to extract "slprop: Information Analysis for Microsoft Office,Show Color next  to Signal,Red" from https://pastebin.com/NRU4vJk6 . Please note there are line breaks.

Answer (score 18):

This might work out for you depending on which language you are using:

```
(?<=Object Name:).*
```

It's a positive lookbehind assertion. More information could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006716/getting-the-text-that-follows-after-the-regex-match).

It won't work with JavaScript though. In your comment I read that you're using it for logstash. If you are using GROK parsing for logstash then it would work. You can verify it yourself here:

**https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/**

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Here's a quick Perl script to get what you need. It needs some whitespace chomping.

```
#!/bin/perl

$sample = <<END;
Subject:
  Security ID:        S-1-5-21-3368353891-1012177287-890106238-22451
  Account Name:       ChamaraKer
  Account Domain:     JIC
  Logon ID:       0x1fffb

Object:
  Object Server:  Security
  Object Type:    File
  Object Name:    D:\\ApacheTomcat\\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\\logs\\localhost.2013- 07-01.log
  Handle ID:  0x11dc
END

my @sample_lines = split /\n/, $sample;
my $path;

foreach my $line (@sample_lines) {
  ($path) = $line =~ m/Object Name:([^s]+)/g;
  if($path) {
    print $path . "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: regex not python

Answer (score -4):

This is a Python solution.

```
import re

line ="""Subject:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-21-3368353891-1012177287-890106238-22451
    Account Name:       ChamaraKer
    Account Domain:     JIC
    Logon ID:       0x1fffb

Object:
    Object Server:  Security
    Object Type:    File
    Object Name:    D:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\logs\localhost.2013-07-01.log
    Handle ID:  0x11dc"""



regex = (r'Object Name:\s+(.*)')
match1= re.findall(regex,line)
print (match1)

*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
['D:\\ApacheTomcat\x07pache-tomcat-6.0.36\\logs\\localhost.2013-07-01.log']
>>>
```