# Regex to match a string and exclude everything else until a new line

Tags: java, regex

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526216/select-the-next-line-after-match-regex) solution somewhat solves my issue but need to exclude any characters after Ordernr until a carriage return(new line)

1. 21Sid1
2. **Ordernr**
3. **E17222**
4. By
5. Seller

I am using ***ordernr[\r\n]+([^\n\r]+)*** to match **ordernr** and **E17222** above. 
I want to do the same for the case below:

1. 21Sid1
2. **Ordernr** Skip everything upto new line
3. **E17222**
4. By
5. Seller

Basically exclude everything when Ordernr is found until a new line and grab the next line

Comment: Java or Javascript?

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245069) Use [edit] option to clarify/correct your question (like updating tags).

Comment: it's for Java. Updated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

`/Ordernr.*[\r\n]+(.*)/g`

Since, `.*` matches everything except line terminators, so we're matching everything after **Ordernr** except new line using `.*` then a new line and again we capture evrything on the next line using `(.*)`.

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/6G8IkK/2)

Here's a sample code in Java:

```
String line = "21Sid1\nOrdernr Skip everything upto new line\nE17222\nBy\nSeller";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Ordernr.*[\r\n]+(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
}else{
    System.out.println("No match found");
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> group 1: E17222

Check the result [here](https://ideone.com/95gDGR).

**EDIT**

To make this regex work with your <sub>dot matches all</sub> consraint, try this:

```
/Ordernr[^\n\r]*[\r\n]+([^\n\r]*)/g
```

here I've replaced dot to match everything except new lines.

Comment: I want to match Ordernr and skip everything till the line terminator and capture everything on the next line. – Currently it matches everything on Ordernr line. Could we just match Ordernr and Skip everything upto new line.

Comment: it's not matching everything, there's a thing called `capturing` in regex, checkout the code and it's output in java : https://ideone.com/95gDGR

Comment: So this is what is happening. I am trying to use it in one of the field processors for JIRA. It works when I try it on live demo sites for both JAVA and JavaScript. However when I try it on the plugin it captures the last line. The reason it is doing that is because of Dot Matches all usage. So basically .* matches all the way to the end and captures the last line instead of next line. Any way to get around this? Here's the screenshot [link](https://pasteboard.co/GPtu179.png)

Comment: what plugin are you talking about?

Comment: It's JEMH for JIRA which uses [link](http://regexpal.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) for regex.

Comment: check the updated answer, it is capturing exactly what you want on your regex tester.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks !

Comment: mark the answer as correct if it solves the issue, it helps future visitors find solution to their problem.

Comment: Hey Ashish, needed a minor update - if I want to capture till a # instead of next line how would I do that?

Comment: `Ordernr[^\n\r]*[\r\n]+([^\n\r#]*)` i.e, just add a `#` to the last set

Comment: Great ! Thank you !

Comment: Hi Ashish, Sorry to chime back in with another request - here's another scenario I would like to capture - I have done some of it but couldn't finish it - would you be able to help>? -

I want to capture Date format - yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm 

**#Date [^\n\r]*[\r\n]+([12]\d{3}/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))**
This expression captures the next line until the day but I wanted to include time part as well and also be able to capture single digits for month and day instead of having to enter two digits - user could enter 5 for month instead of 05 and same for the day.

Comment: it would great if you could post it as a new question @SidhRg