# Match a string in multiline string while excluding special characters

Tags: regex

I have a yaml template with content like that:

Example 1:

```
- key: MY_KEY 
  value: "{{ $MY_VAL }}"
```

Example 2:

```
- key: MY_KEY 
  value: "$MY_VAL"
```

Example 3:

```
- key: MY_KEY 
  value: '$MY_VAL'
```

Example 4:

```
- key: MY_KEY 
  value: 'MY_VAL'
```

I want to match with regex MY_VAL incase of MY_KEY with new line (\r\n) then MY_VAL,
but just incase it's not any kind of variable and it's a real value (e.g alphanumeric).

In the above Example 1 & Example 2 & Example 3 => I want it will return no match.

In Example 4 I want it will return there is a match.

I tried this regex with no success (IMHO I thought it will work, but it's not):

```
MY_KEY[\r\n]+[^${}].[\w].([^\r\n]+)
```

I follow that question of multiline regex, but it's not help in this case:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37526464

Please help :D

Comment: You can't match and remove text with one matching operation. You need to first extract, then remove what you do not want.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for answer. I didn't asked for remove, just regex pattern who will return NoMatch for Example 1,2,3 and Match for Example 4

Comment: Hm, then try `MY_KEY[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]+[^\S\r\n]*\w+:[^\S\r\n]*'(\w+)'`. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t03AGv/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew WOW! AMAZING!! THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
MY_KEY[^\S\r\n]*[\r\n]+[^\S\r\n]*\w+:[^\S\r\n]*'(\w+)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t03AGv/1)

**Details**

- `MY_KEY` - a literal string
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0 or more whitespace chars other than CR and LF
- `[\r\n]+`  - one or more CR or LF chars
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0 or more whitespace chars other than CR and LF
- `\w+` - one or word chars
- `:` - a colon
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0 or more whitespace chars other than CR and LF
- `'(\w+)'` - `'`, 1+ word chars, `'`.