# How do I extract this email address from this multi-line string?

Tags: python, python-re

My workplace has forms sent in via Asana and I am trying to extract the `Recipient Email:` entry and the `Recipient Contact Number:` from the `desc` variable. (note: there are other email & phone numbers I dont want to get in the larger result)

I'm trying to learn after years of PHP & js

The result I want is

> i_want@this.com

but I'm getting

> nah bro

Can anyone nudge me the right way?

```
import re

desc = '''Recipient Email:
i_want@this.com

Recipient Contact Number:
+44(0)0000 000000
'''

email = re.search('Recipient Email:(.*)Recipient Contact Number:', desc)
if email:
    found = email.group(1)
else:
    print('nah bro')
```

Comment: Is it always written like this? I mean why just not try to find email and phone with re itself

Comment: fair, I tried that & it worked. however the full result is bigger & contains other email addresses & phone numbers which I do not need. It's specifically these two, which are going to always be under those headings

Answer (score 1):

You need [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) [even when using `.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

> `re.DOTALL`
> [..] without this flag, `'.'` will match anything *except* a newline. [..]

```py
>>> re.search('Recipient Email:(.*)Recipient Contact Number:', desc, re.DOTALL)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 59), match='Recipient Email:\ni_want@this.com\n\nRecipient Co
```

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thanks so much > re.search('Recipient Email:(.*)Recipient Contact Number:', desc, re.DOTALL)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your regex just doesn't match what you're looking for...
Try this:

```
email = re.search('Recipient Email:[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)', desc)
```

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37526464/9100530) for an explanation of how this regex expression works.

Essentially, we are asking for the characters that come after the line 'Recipient Email:' up until (not including) the next newline character.

Comment: this is brilliant and also works great, it made it simple to repeat a search for the Contact Number on the next line. thanks so much for the tip and link to that post. i'm always learning!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your string is containing enters `\n` and your regular expression is not. You could change your expression to

```py
email = re.search('Recipient Email:\s*(.*)\s*Recipient Contact Number:', desc)
```

`\s` is equivalent to any of these characters `\r\n\t\f\v`

Take a look at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) when making regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  this regex  `[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}`

```py
import re

desc = '''Recipient Email:
i_want@this.com

Recipient Contact Number:
+44(0)0000 000000
'''
regex = r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}"

email = re.search(regex, desc)

if email:
    found = email.group(0)
else:
    print('nah bro')
```

The output that i got

```
i_want@this.com
```