# Regex Match substring if said substring contains another word

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-group, regexp-replace

## Sample String

`Apple, Pinapple, NONE\nOrange, Pears, Apples\nMango, None, Banana\nLemon, NONEDLE, Grape`

### Regex I have tried

`(?<=\\n)(.*?)(?=\\n)` - This matches each of the substrings, but I could not figure out how to only match the ones with NONE in them

### Desired result

I have tried to build a regex that will match each of the lines in the sample string (a line being between one \n to another).
However, I would like it to only match if that line contains the word NONE as a whole word. I have tried to reverse engineer the result from [Regex Match text within a Capture Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082559/regex-match-text-within-a-capture-group?newreg=f347d0e61c79477684bd40cf84fc703c) but wasn't able to get far.

I'm writing a java method that should remove parts of the string that match the regex.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Check [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/kmwuEe).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String input = "Apple, Pinapple, NONE\nOrange, Pears, Apples\nMango, None, Banana\nLemon, NONEDLE, Grape";
input.lines()
    .filter(s -> s.matches(".*\\bNONE\\b.*"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

output

```
Apple, Pinapple, NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries either side of NONE:

```
"(?m)^.*\\bNONE\\b.*$"
```

With multiline flag on, ^ and $ match start and end of lines and since dot doesn’t match newlines, this will match whole lines with NONE is them.

Use this regex with a Matcher; each call to find() will give you the lines you want.