# Smarty regex_replace: how to find one string after match

Tags: regex, replace, smarty

We are trying to use regex_replace in tpl file:

```php
{$item->order->order->notes_priv|regex_replace:"/.+?(?=MATCH)/":""}
```

But this leaves all strings after "MATCH" not the only first one after "MATCH".

We have this text and would like to input only one string after word `MATCH`:

```
foo bar foo bar MATCH 12 foo bar
foo bar foo bar MATCH 24,00 foo bar
```

How we can make input?

```
12
24,00
```

We tried many solutions but without success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to get the words after matching string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193251/regex-to-get-the-words-after-matching-string)

Comment: Does [`MATCH \K\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/8ImTSE/1) work?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. The closest solution is here: {$item->order->order->notes_priv|regex_replace:"/.+?(?=MATCH)/":""}. But it leaves all strings after "MATCH" not the only first one after "MATCH"

Comment: [`.*\bMATCH (\S+).*`/`$1`](https://regex101.com/r/7nhQnI/1) then?

Comment: `regex_replace:'/.+MATCH\s+(\S+).*/':'$1'`

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor. I saw your many replies on similar topics and I was counting on your reply. It is the best solution so far. However it doesn't work with text "MATCH 12 foo bar". In this case the output is "MATCH 12 foo bar". Could you please correct it?

Comment: I have written an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
regex_replace:'/.*MATCH\s+(\S+).*/':'$1'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eSdDyw/1).

The main idea is to match the whole string, capture just a part and replace with a backreference to the captured group value.

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `MATCH` - a literal string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern): any one or more non-whitespace chars
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Comment: Great, Wiktor! Thank you very much for help. Works exactly as we needed.