# How to extract only grouped text using regex with 'g' option in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a url like this:

```
url = http://www.example.com/listing.html?pid=1234&pid=1235&pid=1236
```

How can extract only the value after 'pid=' using regex without the text itself by using the regex.

Here how my regex looks like now:

```
url.match(/pid=(\w+)/g)
```

Which is giving following output:

```
["pid=1234", "pid=1235", "pid=1236"]
```

But I want to get it like this:

```
["1234", "1235", "1236"]
```

Please correct me if I am doing some thing wrong in here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec has an example of how to enumerate regex matches in a string.  The returned object of `RegExp.exec` will give the regex's grouped matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution would be :

```
url.match(/(?<=pid=)(\d+)/g);
```

But, as Javascript doesn't support lookbehind, you'll need to loop over your results :

```
var results = [];
url.match(/pid=(\d+)/g).forEach(function(result) { 
    results.push(result.replace('pid=', '')); 
});

console.log(results); // ["1234", "1235", "1236"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can include something called a positive lookbehind assertion, which is described here: [Getting the text that follows after the regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006716/getting-the-text-that-follows-after-the-regex-match)

I am unable to test whether JavaScript's regexp will do that at the moment, but if so, you're done.  If not, you can do a JS split() on the result of your existing regexp using "=" as the delimiter to get the result you want.  Perhaps not as neat as a single regexp, but it will get the job done.

Edited to add: I was pretty sure zessx would be right even before his comment.  This works:

```
var pids = [];
var url = "http://www.example.com/listing.html?pid=1234&pid=1235&pid=1236";
var result = url.match(/pid=(\w+)/g);
for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
    pids[i] = result[i].split("=")[1];
    console.log(pids[i]);
}
```

Comment: Javascript now supports lookahead, but **doesn't** support lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple functional approach, like this

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/listing.html?pid=1234&pid=1235&pid=1236";

console.log(url.split("&").map(function(currentString) {
    return currentString.split("=")[1];
}));
# [ '1234', '1235', '1236' ]
```

1. First, split the string by `&`
2. And then split each of the split parts by `=` and gather all the second elements

Comment: That works if all the query string parameters are pid=, but can fail if not, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way without spliting/replacing result data:

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/listing.html?pid=1234&pid=1235&pid=1236';    
regex = /(?:pid=)(\w+)/g    
var data =[];

while ((result = regex.exec(url)) !== null) {
  data.push(result[1]);      
}
console.log(data);

// Result Array [ "1234", "1235", "1236" ]
```