# Why is my positive look behind Regex invalid?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression, which will do a positive look behind on the word *google*, and I have tested it for validity using the website **[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)**, which showed me that it works:

```
(?<=google).*
```

I have used it in JavaScript like so:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(?<=google).*');
    someString = "google everything!";

console.log(someString.match(regex)[0]);
```

The console log should return `everything!` with a space behind it, basically all characters excluding new lines after the word *google*.

I have also tried without the need of creating a new RegExp object like so:

```
var someString = "google everything!";
console.log(someString.match(/(?<=google).*/)[0]);
```

... but I get the same error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=google).*/: Invalid group

Comment: There is no lookbehind in JS.

Comment: so the regex is invalid because of JS?

Comment: No, the regex is OK, but JS does not "understand" it :) There are a lot of regex flavors, and some constructs are flavor-dependent. In your case, you just need to use a capturing group: [`google(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/aI1dK0/1). Group 1 holds your data.

Comment: I see (that is unexpected) well then a simple string substring should do the job :) thanks!

Comment: FWIW discussions are currently underway about adding lookbehind support to JavaScript, but it'll probably be a while before anything lands. (I just tried to find a link to the current discussions, but failed.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks this is a very interesting topic I will look into it, I also just realized thanks to the accepted answer, it was a matter of using the wrong regex notation for JavaScript, I was basing mine from Java by mistake, see: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5007710/1046690).

Comment: JavaScript is based on ECMAScript, if you care about regex. And is extremely crippled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex seems incorrect. I'm not sure why you have `<=`. Secondly, you're looking for the second index, not first.

```
var regex = new RegExp('google(.*)'),
    someString = "google everything!",
    matches = someString.match(regex); // ['google everything', ' everything!']
    console.log(matches[1]); //  everything! (with space before it)
```

Comment: This is because I made the mistake of reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5007710/1046690) and not noticing that the language used was Java. Good catch! now all I need is to add a `trim()` to the `matches[1]` and I have what I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

No lookbehind assertions in JS.

You can get around this by using a capture group around just the part
you want to get.

`google(.*)`

Link to try https://jsfiddle.net/vxcdk1kv/

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide a snippet which uses the capture group? I am not clear on how to proceed based of this (purely oblivious)

Comment: Sure hang on, I'm getting a link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression