# How to split a string and get only segament after the question mark

Tags: java, regex, string

how do you split a string and get the sentence only after the question mark. For example say you have the line : hello?myNameIs...

 how could you only get what's after the question mark

 many thanks

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: This `(?<=\?).*`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the text that follows after the regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006716/getting-the-text-that-follows-after-the-regex-match)

Answer (score 0):

If all your use cases will be similar to the simple example you've stated, you could use a simple split.

The code:

```
String delim = "\\?";
String s = "hello?myNameIs";
String token[] = s.split(delim);
System.out.println(token[1]);
```

Gives the output:

```
myNameIs
```

Of course, you can tinker with it to solve your specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
String sArray[]  = src.split(Pattern.quote("?"));
```