# In Python, how can I find a substring that comes after an expression in a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I currently have a large string `big_string` that contains elements like:

```
..."string1":"74f07sdfafeijsfeijfsl","string2":"XRewejffeew","zero_data":{},"string3":"c2d8f4380025",...
```

I would like to extract the string after `"string2"`, so that I can have a variable:

`substring = 'XRewejffeew'`

Is there a way to do this with `re.findall()`?

Comment: Parse the JSON instead, if at all possible

Comment: Yes there is, have you even attempted to do it before asking?

Comment: There are a lot of data requirements and points of interests that I would want to know before making any suggestions. Are commas allowed in the `value`? is everything a basic `key`:`value` pair? Are quotes allowed in either `key`s or `value`s?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findall('(?<="string2":")\w+', big_string) # Result: 'XRewejffeew'
```

For explainations look here:

[Getting the text that follows after the regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006716/getting-the-text-that-follows-after-the-regex-match)